# How to interact on the previous interact by python

Tags: python, optimization, sage

I have tried to create an interact on another interact using the data from the previous one.
But when I try to change data from the first interact, it won't let me change and nothing changes.

```
@interact
def problem(Constraint = 22, Dimension = [2..3],auto_update = False):
   print "The problem is in",Dimension,"dimensions with",Constraint,"constraints"
   @interact(layout=([['c','A','b']]))
   def sub(c = matrix(QQ,Dimension,1), A = matrix(QQ,Constraint,Dimension), b = matrix(QQ,Constraint,1)):
       return
```

I would like to insert the number of constraints and the number of dimensions first. Then, I would like to insert a vector **c**, matrix **A** and vector **b**, respectively. These are the form of linear programming problem.

How should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: This is supposedly possible with some syntax in the Sage cell server http://sagecell.sagemath.org/ but I haven't tried it yet.  A little searching of that, especially its Google+ page, may lead to a solution for you.

Answer (score 1):

Posting on behalf of Sage cell developer Jason Grout - this seems to work verbatim in the [Sage cell server.](http://sagecell.sagemath.org/?q=mafcta)  Cool!  Similar functionality is coming (is in?) the [SageMathCloud](https://cloud.sagemath.com/), but may not be backported to the original notebook.

Comment: See also: list of issues about "interact" in the issue tracker
for the legacy SageNB notebook (feel free to open an issue for
that if there is not already one):
https://github.com/sagemath/sagenb/issues?q=is%3Aissue+interact